# Swift 3 array contains multiple objects by property

Tags: arrays, swift3

I've two structs, a *User* and *Chat*

```
struct User {
    let appId: String
}

struct Chat {
    var users: [User]
}
```

So if you can see a chat can have multiple users.

```
let u1 = User(appId: "12345")
let u2 = User(appId: "6789")
let chat = Chat(users: [u1, u2])
```

Now I'd like to detect if these two users are inside the chat, maybe by the appId

I tried

```
let contains = chat.users.contains { inUser -> Bool in
    return inUser.appId == "12345" && inUser.appId == "6789"
}
```

But for sure that will not work.

Someone can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to know if `u1` and `u2` are into the chat you should write

```
let bothInChat = chat.users.contains { $0.appId == "12345" } && chat.users.contains { $0.appId == "6789" }
```

Comment: Dooooh, that easy one ... thank's a lot. I thought too complicated.